# Understanding npm's package.json to git version association

Tags: git, npm

I'm about to publish my first npm package and I'm not sure I understand how versioning works.

Let's say I have a typical package.json containing a version number and a reference to a git repository where the package is hosted and its published and all is good. Now lets say I update the version number, push some changes to the repo and re-publish the package to npm as with a new version number

What happens to the previously published version of the package - does npm maintain somewhere an association between that older published version and the commit at the time it was published?

I presume that old package won't suddenly start referencing the newly pushed repo, but don't understand how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/publish.html), `npm publish`:

> publishes a package to the registry so that it can be installed by name.

The actual artifact pushed to the registry is a gzip'd tarball.

So running `npm install foobar@1.0.0` downloads the foobar tarball package from the npm registry, and never involves your git repo in any way. Running `npm install foobar@2.0.0` would also download from the npm registry.

The [package.json repository field](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html#repository) is an optional field to:

> Specify the place where your code lives. This is helpful for people who want to contribute. If the git repo is on github, then the npm docs command will be able to find you.

Comment: "The actual artifact pushed to the registry is a gzip'd tarball." - if only the doco said that somewhere!